# CPA-security of a pseudorandom permutation encryption scheme

Tags: provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, pseudo-random-permutation

> Let $F$ be a pseudorandom permutation, and define a fixed-length
>   encryption scheme $(Gen, Enc, Dec)$ as follows: on input $m \in$
>   $\{0,1\}^{n/2}$ and key $k \in \{0,1\}^n$, algorithm $Enc$ chooses a
>   random string $r \leftarrow \{0,1\}^{n/2}$ of length $n/2$ and
>   computes $c = F_k(r||m)$. Show how to decrypt, and prove that this
>   scheme is CPA-secure for messages of length $n/2$.

I see the decryption could be $d = F_k^{-1}(c) = r||m \Rightarrow r_0r_1 ... r_{n/2-1} m_0m_1 ... m_{n/2-1}$, assuming $n$ is even the receiver knows that he must extract $m$ from the first exact half (from right to left) in the ciphertext sequence. As for the CPA-security, I notice that $F_k$ is non deterministic because of $r$, so for a message $m$ the 2 ciphertexts $c = F_k(r||m)$ and $c' = F_k(r'||m)$ are different if $r \neq r'$. Let $q(n)$ be a polynomial number of oracle queries, then $r = r'$ with probability $$\frac{q(n)}{2^{n/2}}$$ which should be negligible.
Is that correct? And should I say something about the security parameter $n$? I feel I'm missing something here.

Comment: You appear to be missing the "prove that this scheme is CPA-secure for ..." part. $\;$

Comment: You implicitly consider an adversary which follows some *specific* strategy. You must show that the probability is negligible for *all* polynomial-time adversaries. Namely, you must show that the existence of a polynomial-time adversary which succeeds in breaking CPA-security would contradict the assumed pseudorandomness of $F$.

Comment: @fkraiem so I should first define the CPA indistinguishability game (IND-CPA) considering 2 cases: this encryption scheme (A); and the encryption scheme (B) exactly the same as A, except that it uses $f \leftarrow Func_n$ instead of $F_k$. Then reducing it (the IND_CPA game) to the distinguishing between $F_k$ and **f** level ?

Comment: No, you first assume that there is some adversary $A$ which succeeds in breaking the CPA-security, and then you construct an algorithm $D$ which can distinguish $F_k$ from a uniformly chosen *pemutation*. Your algorithm $D$ will use $A$ as a subroutine (*i.e.*, it will call $A$ on some appropriate inputs, and will use $A$'s answer as a hint to help it distinguish $F_k$ from a uniform permutation).

Comment: @fkraiem ok, then I apply the above steps, concluding that it happens with negligible probability resulting in a contradiction? Therefore $A$ doesn't succeed in breaking the CPA-security.

Comment: No, the proof is by contradiction: you show that $D$ *does* succeed in distinguishing $F_k$ from a random permutation. This is a contradiction because $F_k$ is pseudorandom, and hence $A$ cannot exist.

Comment: This scheme is in fact CCA secure (if F is a strong PRP). I show a proof of its CCA security in [section 10.5 of my textbook](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~rosulekm/crypto/). Proof of CPA security (from plain PRP property) would be significantly simpler. The proofs in this book follow a game-hopping style.

Comment: @Mikero we have another question. Could you write at least a partial answer so we can close the other as dupe?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. As Mikero noted in the comments, this scheme is CCA-secure as proven in [his book](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~rosulekm/crypto/).

The proof strategy that seems easiest here is to do game-hops and with the IND$-CPA definition:

- Start with the real case where $c=F_K(r\mathbin\|m)$ is returned
- Swap out $F_K(\cdot)$ for a random permutation $\pi$, so $c=\pi(r\mathbin\|m)$ is returned, you "lose" the PRP advantage on your bound here
- Swap out $\pi$ for a random function $f$ using the PRP-PRF-switching lemma, so $c=f(r\mathbin\|m)$ is returned, you lose the PRP-PRF bound here (additively)
- Swap out $f$ for the function that instead drops its input and instead returns a fresh random value, you additively lose the probability you named because only if $r$'s (and $m$'s) repeat there's a chance that you can distinguish this from the previous game, $c\gets \{0,1\}^n$
- Now you always return a random value as the ciphertext, independent of the input message, therefore it cannot convey any information about it, you're done

> Is that correct?

The basic idea is there, it just needs to be spelled out a bit more explicitly.