# Prove that the given scheme is CPA secure or not

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

**Given:**

F is a length preserving PRP. 
Encryption scheme $\Pi$ for messages of n/2 bits where:
$m\in\{0,1\}^{n/2}$
$k\in\{0,1\}^n$
Enc: Select a random string $r\in\{0,1\}^{n/2}$ and output  $c\leftarrow F_k(r||m)$

**Prove:**
If this scheme is CPA secure or not.

My approach so far has been to Prove this using reduction by designing an Attacker $A$ who can break this scheme with non negligible probability, Using that attacker I am trying to break PRP with non negligible probability but that would give a contradiction and hence this scheme is CPA Secure. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Also can we ever say with 100% certainty that a scheme is secure by this approach?

Also, my understanding to prove these kind of things is :

To prove that a give scheme is insecure design an attacker for the given scheme

To prove that a given scheme is COA/CPA secure design an attacker who can break the scheme with non negligible probability and reach a contradiction somewhere

Am I missing something here?

Is the above scheme CPA secure? How to prove it?

Comment: They will be different since we have a random string $r$ which will get padded with the message every time.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I missed that part. ​ I think the idea will be showing that PRPs with large domain are also PRFs. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I think that part is obvious right? PRPs are a special case of PRF. What do you think about CPA security of this scheme? Will reduction be a right approach?

Comment: [PRPs with small domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) are not PRFs. ​ ​ ​ I think the [flag bad](http://cr.yp.to/bib/2004/bellare-games.pdf) should be set if and only if the random function is called more than once on ​ r || challenge_plaintext . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: This one is straightforward: the PRP distinguisher uses its internal oracle to emulate $\Pi$, and uses the assumed CPA adversary to distinguish messages produced by F from random ones.

Comment: That's exactly the approach I mentioned in my question. So it would be enough to prove the security here?

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you are asking, but yes, this would be the standard way to proceed. You probably have such proofs in your textbook as well.

Comment: I am asking if the approach that I am taking is correct or not because it surprises me that it works so easily.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this: also see [this older Q/A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27172/23623).